# What's the difference between using Angular as a package for Node.js and as a regular imported library in your html?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

Are there advantages from one over the other? Are these the same thing and I'm confused?

If there is a reason why Angular package for node.js was created please explain to me, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new angular which is a framework available in node js as npm package is different from the old Angularjs library

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-AngularJs-and-Angular-2